# create a heatmap with regions in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following kind of data: on a rectangular piece of land (120x50 yards), there are 6 (also rectabgular) smaller areas each with a different kind of plant. The idea is to study the attractiveness of the various kinds of plant to birds. Each time a bird sits down somewhere on the land, I have the exact coordinates of where the bird sits down. 
I don't care exactly where the bird sits down, but only care which of the six areas it is. To show the relative preference of birds for the various plants, I want to make a heatmap that makes the areas that are frequented most the darkest.
So, I need to convert the coordinates to code which area the bird visits, and then create a heatmap that shows the differential preference for each land area.
(the research is a bit more involved than this, but this is the general idea.)

How would I do this in R? Is there a R function that takes a vector of coordinates and turns that in such a heatmap? If not, do you have some hints for more on how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Not meant to be the answer you are looking for, but might give you some inspiration.

```
# Simulate some data
birdieLandingSimulator <- data.frame(t(sapply(1:100, function(x) c(runif(1, -10,10), runif(1, -10,10)))))

# Assign some coordinates, which ended up not really being used much at all, except for the point colors
assignCoord <- function(x)
  {
  # Assign the four coordinates clockwise: 1, 2, 3, 4
  ifelse(all(x>0), 1, ifelse(!sum(x>0), 3, ifelse(x[1]>0, 2, 4)))
}
birdieLandingSimulator <- cbind(birdieLandingSimulator, Q = apply(birdieLandingSimulator, 1, assignCoord))

# Plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(birdieLandingSimulator, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) +
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = 1/..density..), contour = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Q))) + theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE, h=c(180, 270)) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Birdie Landing Location")
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful! And, indeed, an inspiring example.

Answer (score 2):

Use ggplot2.  Take a look at the examples for [geom_bin2d](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bin2d.html).  It's pretty simple to get 2d bins.  Notice that you pass in binwidth for both x and y:

```
> df = data.frame(x=c(1,2,4,6,3,2,4,2,1,7,4,4),y=c(2,1,4,2,4,4,1,4,2,3,1,1))
> ggplot(df,aes(x=x, y=y,alpha=0.5)) + geom_bin2d(binwidth=c(2,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ggplot, you can use the `cut` function to separate your data into bins.

```
    # Test data.
    x <- sample(1:120, 100, replace=T)
    y <- sample(1:50, 100, replace=T)

    # Separate the data into bins.
    x <- cut(x, c(0, 40, 80, 120))
    y <- cut(y, c(0, 25, 50))

    # Now plot it, suppressing reordering.
    heatmap(table(y, x), Colv=NA, Rowv=NA)
```

Alternatively, to actually plot the regions in their true geographic location, you could draw the boxes yourself with `rect`. You would have to count the number of points in each region.

```
    # Test data.
    x <- sample(1:120, 100, replace=T)
    y <- sample(1:50, 100, replace=T)
    regions <- data.frame(xleft=c(0, 40, 40, 80, 0, 80),
                          ybottom=c(0, 0, 15, 15, 30, 40),
                          xright=c(40, 120, 80, 120, 80, 120),
                          ytop=c(30, 15, 30, 40, 50, 50))

    # Color gradient.
    col <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(30)

    # Make the plot.
    plot(NULL, xlim=c(0, 120), ylim=c(0, 50), xlab="x", ylab="y")
    apply(regions, 1, function (r) {
        count <- sum(x >= r["xleft"] & x < r["xright"] & y >= r["ybottom"] & y < r["ytop"])
        rect(r["xleft"], r["ybottom"], r["xright"], r["ytop"], col=col[count])
        text( (r["xright"]+r["xleft"])/2, (r["ytop"]+r["ybottom"])/2, count)
    })
```

[image]

Comment: This can work. The only thing is that I need to be able to plot the areas in their actual location. Does "heatmap" (or ggplot) do that? All areas are rectangular, but not all of the same size. So, I want to maintain their actual size and location. Can that be done?

Comment: As far as I know, heatmap cannot do that. ggplot perhaps, I'm not sure. I edited my answer to another (slightly clumsy) way in base R, hope you get some ideas.